# Want to play audio file from data/data/package_name/files path

Tags: android, media-player

In my application i am storing audio files in `data/data/package_name/files/Folder/` folder now I want to play these audio files using object of MediaPlayer I tried 2 ways for this but could not make it possible.

```
using player.setDataSource(path) //and by using
 MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),Uri.fromFile(path)).
```

Is there any way so that i could play the audio.By trying above i am getting this

```
01-24 11:35:13.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 11:35:13.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064): java.lang.NullPointerException
runtime exception.
```

Please help me.
I have also tried

```
try {
                Log.d("1","1");
                File mFile = new File("/data/data/com.lister.viewer/files/com.aaa.0001/audio.wav");
                Log.d("2","2");
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFile);
                Log.d("3","3");
                player.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());         
                Log.d("4","4");
                player.prepare();
                Log.d("5","5");

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("6","6");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("7","7");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("8","8");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("9","9");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("10","10");
            player.start();
            Log.d("11","11");
```

this code and log is

```
01-24 12:33:31.468: DEBUG/1(11457): 1
01-24 12:33:31.488: DEBUG/2(11457): 2
01-24 12:33:31.488: DEBUG/3(11457): 3
01-24 12:33:31.518: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(11457): Shutting down VM
01-24 12:33:31.527: WARN/dalvikvm(11457): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught 
exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-24 12:33:31.558: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 12:33:31.558: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11457): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

One more thing i would tell that when i wrote player=new MediaPlayer(); above File mFile = new File("/data/data/com.lister.viewer/files/com.aaa.0001/audio.wav"); then it is not throwing exception But still i could not hear sound and the logcat is as below.

```
01-24 12:49:59.467: DEBUG/1(16108): 1
01-24 12:49:59.507: DEBUG/2(16108): 2
01-24 12:49:59.507: DEBUG/3(16108): 3
01-24 12:50:00.358: DEBUG/4(16108): 4
01-24 12:50:00.368: DEBUG/5(16108): 5
01-24 12:50:00.368: DEBUG/10(16108): 10
01-24 12:50:00.379: DEBUG/AudioSink(34): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-24 12:50:00.408: DEBUG/11(16108): 11
```

why it is giving bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12. where should i increase it????any more setting that is needed for it??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, blindly assumption,

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
File mFile = new File("data/data/package_name/files path");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFile);
mPlayer.reset();
mPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());         
mPlayer.prepare();
```

Also make sure your Audio file has a **world Readable permission..**

Check it using `DDMS` or in `adb shell ls -al /data/data/package_name/myfile`

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i am getting the same exception. :(

Comment: I have edited my question above please tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: You didn't give full information of your code and log errors, anyway you have a null pointer exception from line  player.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());  so just check for your media player object have you initialized it properly..

Comment: Sorry but i could not disclose my full code so i have given the neccesary part  of code where I am getting exception.And yes as you said i have initialised the media player object then exception is not thrown but i could not hear that audio file and in my log cat i could see the line "01-24 12:50:00.379: DEBUG/AudioSink(34): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12" what does it mean? I don't know how to increase buffer size